# Gentilicio para Austria ¿Qué determina el empleo de una u otra forma?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, acentuación, dialectos

Después de una jornada en Portugal donde pasé unos días en un grupo que incluía, entre otros, una mujer de Austria. En portugués, la palabra es *austríaca*, y al llegar a España y hablar de este grupo (bien por influencia del portugués bien por quizás así haberlo aprendido en castellano), usé esta misma palabra solo para que un amigo mío, natural de España, me corrigiese, indicando la forma «correcta» de *austriaca* (sin tilde).

Resulta que, en el DRAE, figuran las dos formas, pero el DPD carece de entrada sobre el gentilicio.

Entonces, mi pregunta llega a ser la siguiente: **¿Qué determina el empleo de una u otra forma?** Si es geografía/dialecto, ¿dónde prevalece cada forma? ¿O podría ser registro o período<sup>1</sup> histórico?

---

<sup>1. Período/periodo es otra palabra que presenta una parecida variación que tal vez merecería otra pregunta.</sup>

Comment: Se me ocurre también *cardíaco/cardiaco*. Por mi parte uso la forma esdrújula en estos casos.

Comment: En el DPD entrada [Apéndice 5: Lista de países y capitales, con sus gentilicios](http://lema.rae.es/dpd//apendices/apendice5.html) se lee: _Austria. País de Europa. Gent. austriaco, -ca o austríaco, -ca. Cap. Viena._

Comment: @fedorqui me refería a una explicación de la distribución, tal como detalle para vídeo/video

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El Diccionario panhispánico de dudas tiene una entrada sobre esto:

> [**-íaco -ca** o **-iaco -ca**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxX7DyBYND6GTUSZdW).
>
> 1. Sufijo que forma adjetivos que indican relación con lo designado por el sustantivo base: elegíaco o elegiaco (‘de la elegía’), austríaco o austriaco (‘de Austria’).

Pero lo importante viene en el 2.º punto:

> 2. La acentuación etimológica latina es *-íaco* [í - a - ko], con hiato entre las dos vocales en contacto; pero también es correcta la acentuación llana *-iaco* [iá - ko], con diptongo en lugar de hiato. En el español americano, la norma culta prefiere la acentuación esdrújula ([maníako]); en el español de España es más corriente la pronunciación llana ([maniáko]). Se recomienda adecuar la grafía a la pronunciación, de modo que quien pronuncie un hiato escriba *-íaco* y quien pronuncie un diptongo escriba *-iaco*.

Por lo que tu duda parece quedar resuelta:

- **En Hispanoamérica generalmente dirán *austríaco*.**
- **En España generalmente dirán *austriaco*.**

Comment: Curioso... yo soy de México y siempre he dicho (y leído) "austriaco" ([*austriáko*]

Comment: @Barranka y yo de España y suelo decir _austríaco_ (_[austríako]_) :)

Comment: Buena cosa. En Chile usamos ambas formas y no sé dónde está la línea divisoria. Yo uso la forma esdrújula y mi esposa la llana.

Comment: @fedorqui debido a estos comentarios, me temo decir que talvez debemos añadir también una respuesta comunitaria para indicar zonas de preferencia. (En tu caso, ¿tal vez sea por influencia del catalán como obviamente lo fue para mí con portugués?)

Comment: Concuerdo que en México se es común decir Austriaco con acentuación llana.

Answer (score 1):

En los comentarios a la [respuesta de fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21550/1674) se generó un bonito intercambio de impresiones sobre qué lugares usan uno u otro vocablo. Dado que la realidad parece más heterogénea de lo que indica el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, animo a que cada uno liste a continuación los lugares donde se usa una u otra opción.

### Lugares donde se pronuncia **austríaco** (con tilde)

- España → allí donde hay influencia catalana.
- España → allí donde hay influencia gallega.

### Lugares donde se pronuncia **austriaco** (sin tilde)

- México
- España → allí donde no hay otra lengua cooficial.

Comment: es posible que en zonas gallegohablantes también sea *austríaco* porque lo es en gallego (el asturiano, a cambio, solo tiene *austriaco*).  ¿Tenemos algún gallego por aquí para confirmárnoslo?

Comment: En el País Vasco aunque he oído las dos predomina la forma llana. Y tenemos lengua cooficial aunque no es romance :)

Comment: Los gallegos a los que he preguntado dicen austriaco, pero llevan años en el País Vasco así que no puedo asegurar que otros gallegos pronuncien igual

Comment: @blonfu qué bien recibir tu comentario. Dado que esta es una respuesta wiki, dale al [edit] sin vergüenza y añade esa parte ;-)

Comment: Lamento no aportar la pronunciación chilena, se dan ambas formas.

Comment: Por alusiones, gallegoparlante que ha residido el 90% de su vida en Galicia, yo pronuncio con acento en la I, _austríaco_.

Comment: @Alicia ¡grande! Edité la respuesta para añadir tu dato. Siéntete libre de editar la publicación tú misma, pues es "wiki de comunidad" y las ponemos así precisamente para que se puedan mejorar entre todos. [What are Community Wiki posts?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)