# Words with different pronunciations

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, pronunciación, sílabas

Does Spanish have words which can be pronounced with a different number of syllables? For example, in English one can pronounce `lightning` with 2 syllables, meaning the companion of thunder, and 3 syllables, meaning brightening.

I was wondering if Spanish has such words as well.

Comment: I think you will find that to make lighter is spelled lightening so you need a different example.

Comment: @mdewey I was relying on [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lightning)

Comment: I think you misunderstood what wiktionary says in that entry.  (Thanks for posting the link.)

Comment: @aparente001 Could you elaborate? I was referring to meanings 1 and 4 of the word.

Comment: Related --> [Gentilicio para Austria ¿Qué determina el empleo de una u otra forma?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/gentilicio-para-austria-qu%C3%A9-determina-el-empleo-de-una-u-otra-forma). There you have a suffix whose pronunciation differs from one region to the other.

Comment: The wikitionary entry is copied from Webster which is an US source and their spelling must differ from British English, the southern English dialect of which is what i speak.

Comment: @dimid - Meaning 1 gives an example sentence and the word is clearly spelled "lightning."  Meaning 4 explains what this meaning of the word is, by referencing a couple of other words, including "brightening," but you should not jump from that to "lightening."  It doesn't say "lightening."  Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but they tend to be barely perceptible to the average speaker because they tend to be based on dialect. For example, the word *guion* can be pronounced in one (/'gjon/) or two (/gi'on/) syllables. There is no change in meaning however.  As the [Ortografía](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fubocfstcPJOpVEx) points out:

> Estas secuencias <sub>[de vocal cerrada átona y vocal abierta tónica]</sub>, que en España y en una parte de América se articulan en muchos vocablos como hiatos, se pronuncian, en cambio, como diptongos o integrando triptongos en otras zonas, especialmente en México, Centroamérica y parte de las áreas caribeña y andina.  Así palabras como *piano, enviar, guion, jesuita, diurno* o *fieis* son silabeadas por unos hispnohablantes separando  las vocales contiguas en sílabas distintas: [pi.á.no], [em.bi.ár], [gi.ón], [je.su.í.ta], [di.úr.no], [fi.éis]; y por otros, agrupando las vocales dentro de la misma sílaba: [piá.no], [em.biár], [gión], [je.suí.ta], [diúr.no], [fiéis].

Sometimes you can have a hiatus in unstressed syllables and some speakers will have the resulting extra syllable. For example, any word with the prefix *bio-* which can be either /bi.o/ or /bjo/.  The reasons for when someone would use one pronunciation or another are quite varied:

> La articulación de determinadas secuencias vocálicas dentro de la misma sílaba o en sílabas distintas no solo depende de la procedencia geográfica, sino que se ve influida asimismo por otros factores, como la posición que la secuencia ocupa dentro de la palabra, la velocidad de emisión, el mayor o meno esmero en la pronunciación, la etimología o la analogía con otras palabras de la misma familia léxica, etc.

But these differences are not (by design) indicated in writing except when they affect the stressed syllable (as in *vídeo ~ video*, but those are spelt differently so they don't count as an answer to your question :-) ).  None of these will affect the meaning of the word, however, as can happen in English *read* /riːd/ ~ *read* /rɛd/.

Comment: I've come across a spectacular exception.  I asked directions to the "Paseo Bravo."  It took me a while to understand the answer (from a random person): she directed me on how to get to the Paseo Brap.

Comment: Thanks, are there regional differences between /bi.o/ and /bjo/ or is it a just a personal choice?

Comment: @dimid neither really. It's pretty spontaneous for any possible hiatuses like that. Most speakers aren't even aware that such a thing exists (unlike words like guion where they tend to hear it slightly)

Comment: That is wrong in many dimensions.
The problem with **Bio**, for example, is that if you assume **Bio-tecnológico** as two words, people tend to accent it in some way as if they were really two words: **Bio** and **Tecnológico**. So where should **Bio** has the accent? The tilde should be in **Bío** (/bi.o/) but not in Bio (/bjo/) (monosyllable).

Comment: But the rule says that the particle is not accented: **Biotecnológico** (which is correct) Is going to sound like /bjo/. But **Bio-tecnológico**, is felt like two words, therefore getting the two accents wrongly stressed: Bío-Tecnológico. And coming the particle from Bio (greek for live, life) is a compositional particle (Bio does not exist as a word in spanish, just as a prefix) the supposition that a wrong spelled word is a "regional difference" is absurd, specially when spanish is super straight forward in the pronunciation.

Comment: @billeeb Note that I did **not** say that *bio-* is stressed or accented, I said that it can have a hiatus. A hiatus can only be explicitly marked if the weak vowel receives the stress, otherwise it is hidden (another example: *enviar* which will be pronounced as either /en'bjar/ or /en.bi'ar/). The Spanish orthography system has no way of marking this, except in poetry where a dieresis is used to force the two-syllable pronunciation, and most speakers will end up realizing the pronunciation both ways, hence negating the need to mark it regularly.

Comment: Por favor lee lo que se detalle en la *Nueva Ortografía* (2010), específicamente en los apartados 3.2h y 3.2i (págs. 223-224).

Comment: I don't get a dieresis in a non accented word. Día, has it. Stating that whenever a diptong has stress in the weak vowel then the hiatus is broken by the diéresis, and the stress is visible with a tilde, even when accentuation rules would no allow it normally. Dieretic accent.

Comment: A link to that??

Comment: Other examples memoria. Ia is diptong, stress in the a has no tilde. Diario. Ia and io are diptongs, the word is stressed in the a, no diptong is broken by dieresis and is a "grave" word ended in vocal, so, no tilde.

Comment: The diéresis is not a lyrical tool, is a grammatical rule!!!

Comment: http://aplica.rae.es/ortografia/

Comment: @billeeb Also note the difference between a dieresis (as in *rüido*, *süave*, or *fïel*) and an acute accent (called *tilde* in Spanish, as in *alemán*, *alcántara*, *librería*). The acute marks the stress, and as the *Ortografía* notes, that it marks hiatuses is a side effect. The dieresis, outside of its use in *-güe-* or *güi* combinations, is used to indicate, for metric reasons, the obligatory nature of a hiatus.

Comment: In the previous comment I said all the time diéresis but I was refferring to the interruption of the hiatus by the dieretical accent. Forget about the diéresis, it should be read as hiatus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71831/discussion-between-billeeb-and-guifa).